# Launch a screen flow from Process builder

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

**Requirements**

I have business requirement that is

- launch a flow upon status change of Quote, asking user if he/she wants to close the related opportunity?
- upon checking the checkbox on the flow-screen, the related opportunity needs to be closed.

**Solution**

I have created a screen-flow, I know that [flow type must be autolaunch flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_flow.htm&type=5) to appear in the process builder, but requirements need user-interaction. How should I achieve this?

Comment: What should happen if status is changed by API call? Answer of this question should define your solution strategy pretty much

Comment: There won’t be any update through the api. I know what you’re getting at, but that’s what it is.

Comment: Can't you use an Action with a checkbox here? Might be the easiest way

Comment: @fred can you give an example ?

Comment: @Mahmood: Example added as answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of an implementation via an Action on the Quote Object:

[image]

When the checkbox is changed, you can use a PB to update the related Opportunity.

To create an action, navigate to the Object Manager, choose Buttons, Links and Actions, and create a new Action. Choose to update a record, and select the checkbox field in the Page Layout. In the 'Predefined Field Values' section, set your Quote status to 'Accepted'.

Repeat the steps for a 'Quote Denied' action.

Comment: Ah the quick action! I actually want to have this action on change of Quote status value change; that won't be possible from that.

Comment: That's right, given your use case I thought this comes close to what you want without too much hassle

Answer (score 2):

Process builder cannot be used to launch an interactive flow (one with user screens), from Salesforce documentation an autolaunched flow:

> Doesn’t require user interaction. This flow type doesn’t support screens, local actions, steps, choices, or dynamic choices.

[SF Help on Flow Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_admin_flow_type.htm&type=5)

So that would not be an option for your scenario.

Either the Quote screen needs to be replaced with an interactive flow to update it so that the user can be directed or another approach would be required to capture the user input, such as sending a chatter message or email with the linked opportunity record prompting the user about changing the status.

Comment: Interesting! I like the "Email with linked record" approach; but I have opted for a slightly different yet simple approach.